# Why is my (id == null) returning null on my update method in Entity Framework MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, crud

Ok, so I've posted a few things that I'm doing with this project. I'm still learning. Anyway, my controller when it is calling the view for my update method. I'm getting null for the id parameter. I set a breakpoint on if(id == null) on my ActionResult Edit action, and when I run it; it shows null within the breakpoint autos window. Can someone please tell me why I'm getting null when there is data in my database?

MusicController.cs

```
// GET: Songs/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Song song = db.Songs.Find(id.Value);
        if (song == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(song);
    }
```

Edit.cshtml

```
@model MusicManager.Models.Song

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit Songs";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SongName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.SongName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter song name here" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ArtistName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ArtistName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter artist name here" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AlbumName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AlbumName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter ablum name here" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Duration, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter duration as x.xx" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Exclude) @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Exclude)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="pad-top">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg margin-right">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
        </button>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Music")" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @model List<MusicManager.Models.Song>

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Music";
    }

    <div id="addButton">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg margin-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", "Music", null, new { @class="addButton" })</button>
</div>

    <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Song</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Album</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var song in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@song.Id</td>
            <td>@song.SongName</td>
            <td>@song.ArtistName</td>
            <td>@song.AlbumName</td>
            <td>@song.Duration.ToString("0.00")</td>
            <td>
                <div class="pull-right">                   
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm margin-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Music", new { id = song.Id })</span></button>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = song.Id })" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Delete</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Song.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MusicManager.Models
{
public class Song
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Song()
    { }

    /// <summary>
    ///  The Id of the song.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  The name of the song.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Song")]
    public string SongName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The artist of the song.
    /// </summary>
    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Artist")]
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an album from an artist.
    /// </summary>
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Album")]
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  The duration of the song.
    /// </summary>
    public double Duration { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Whether or not this song should be excluded when calculating the total duration of the current playlist. 
    /// </summary>
    public bool Exclude { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Is `id` null, or is `song` null?

Comment: Do u mean the id u r passing to ur controller action is always null? or u mean that inspite of havind data in ur database against some id, entity framework is returning null?

Comment: The only issue I see here is that `id` is Nullable. Try `db.Songs.Find(id.Value)`, probably it could work? Also if not - look at `db.Songs.ToList()` in debugger to see what stored in your db

Comment: Id is null, there are songs in the database. The id auto-increments with the songs in the database, so entity framework is returning null. I also tried `db.Songs.Find(id.Value)`, but it is returning null on `if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }`

Comment: @HanSolo0001 You are calling your Edit method in a wrong way. You need to pass the song's Id value in your Action Link while calling to Edit method, then only it will have some real value. Check my bellow answer, i already mentioned everything.

Comment: @Steve Yes `id` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are calling Edit from some page, then your Action link will be like this,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Music", new{ id = value })
```

> Here first Edit is just a Name. Second Edit is your Action Method name and Music is your controller name where Edit Action method present.

In your Song model class, make Id nullable.

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
```

In your question,in "Edit.cshtml", you are submitting a form to **HttpGet** method. It should be **HttpPost** method. And you need to include id in your Edit form as hidden field(if you dont want to show), like bellow,

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) //This is your Song Id
```

This will be before close braces **}** of **form** in Edit view.

Comment: Basanta, I am first trying to get it to where when I click on my edit button, it takes me to the edit.cshtml page.

Comment: Are you able to pass value in your id field ? In your edit.cshtml keep your songID in a hiddenfor. Then when you click save button, it will call http post edit action method.

Comment: I've tried those ways but I keep getting 400 errors. I am currently just trying to access my Edit page, where it will have a save button and then that will be posted to the database and update it. However, I'm not there yet. I have re-edited my code to follow you (if I'm understanding you correctly) @Basanta. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 400 because you changed your Edit method to HttpPost. It should be HttpGet. And create a HttpPost Edit method, that will call after click on Save button inside Edit.cshtml. Otherwise your code seems correct only. Change to HttpGet and remove ? from int and check once and let me know.

Comment: Oh! here the song id you are passing in wrong way id = song.Id. It should be id = @song.Id. Check once and let me know.

Comment: Ok tried all that, but id is still returning null. Here's the error when I click on Edit to get to the edit page. 

"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'MusicManager.Controllers.MusicController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters"

If it helps any, I forgot to mention I have this project on GitHub.
https://github.com/HanSolo0001/Music-Manager

Comment: @HanSolo0001 In ur Song model class make id nullable. It should be public int? Id {get;set;} It will solve ur problem. If it will solve ur problem, make it answer :)

Comment: Still getting null for id field.

Comment: I check your code in git. In EditHttpGet method, change this line to,            var Song = db.Songs.Select(i => i.Id == id); Or-else you can write var Song = db.Songs.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();  And in Song class make id nullable like, i said in my previous comment.

Comment: Is that solved ?? Let me know. BDW in your Edit HttpPost method change this Edit(int? id, FormCollection collection).    I just added ? in int id

Comment: still not solved. 

`// GET: Songs/Edit/5
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var Song = db.Songs.Select(i => i.Id == id);
            if (Song == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(Song);
        }
`

Here is my Get method on Edit. Id is still null which is why I keep hitting HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request. It hits it first if id = null.

Comment: @HanSolo0001 what error are you getting here ? Did you go through my previous comments. You need to change what ever I told.

Comment: here is the error I'm getting when I click on Edit:
[link](http://imgur.com/a/FRwwv). When I type in the address bar "Music/Edit/5" I get this error:

    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Boolean]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MusicManager.Models.Song'.

Comment: Why don't you return FirstOrDefault(). If you don't do like this then update this in your Edit view @model IEnumerable<MusicManager.Models.Song>

Comment: we're getting somewhere now. 2 issues now arise. When I clcik Edit, it takes me to a 400 error page. However, when I type in Edit/5 like within my comment code right above the `// GET: Songs/Edit/5 [HttpGet]`, I then get to the right page. So that needs fixing. Second issue will be posted below.

Comment: `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Song>' does not contain a definition for 'SongName' and no extension method 'SongName' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Song>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Source Error:

Line 13:  <div class="col-md-6">
Line 14:  <div class="form-group">               
Line 15:   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SongName, new { @class = "control-label" })
Line 16:   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.SongName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter song name here" })
Line 17:   </div>`

Comment: when I change my code to use the FirstOrDefault(), I then get this error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Comment: @HanSolo0001 Man You stuck in a silly mistake. Your controller name is Music. Your Method name is Edit. Then how can you access your Edit view by calling Songs/Edit/5  in URL ? you should type Music/Edit/5

Comment: Upon using a breakpoint, I am still getting this code returning null on id before reaching where I have var Song =... :
 `if(id == null) {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var Song = db.Songs.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Sorry URL is returning Music/Edit/5. Was using that comment as an example of how I typed it in. I'll re-update my GitHub to my current code. Maybe you can fork it or download it to Visual Studio to see better on what I see in these errors I'm getting. With id still being null, I believe that's my number one issue still. The page should return as localhost:portnumber/Music/Edit, just like the Add page is returned localhost:portnumber/Music/Add.

Comment: Here's my GitHub page for this project. https://github.com/HanSolo0001/Music-Manager

Comment: I checked you code. I think you have not gone through my above answer at all. Just read the answer what i wrote. In your Index page you are calling like this @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Music", null, new { @class="editButton" }). Check my answer above how I'm passing parameter. And you can't call your Edit method like this localhost:portnumber/Music/Edit as your Edit method need a parameter called id. So it should be Music/Edit/Value. Value will be song Id. Example 1 or 2 or etc. Hope you can solve now. If it helps plz dont forget to mark as answer :)

Comment: Are you saying that I need to set it up as this? `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Music", new { id = value })`? If so, I get an error (red squiggly) under value saying it doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: @HanSolo0001 You need to pass your value in "value". For example 1 or 2 or 5 or any value. In your question, you have written correctly, like @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Music", new { id = song.Id }).

Comment: I got it fixed! Thank you for your help! All I had to do was add in new {id=song.Id}, and no int? id either in HttpGet "public ActionResult Edit(int id)" or "public int Id { get; set; }"